# CruiseControl.NET Web Dashboard resets when ccnet.config is updated

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Whenever we update the ccnet.config file for the CruiseControl.NET server, anyone who is logged in starts getting exceptions in the Web Dashboard:

> Request processing has failed on the remote server: Permission to execute 'ViewProject' has been denied.

I imagine this is because when the ccnet server restarts, the web dashboard's connection to it is reset as well, and the session token (which is stored in a cookie as a Guid) becomes invalid.

Is there any way around this?  It's really annoying when testing out a bunch of configuration changes to lose your login each time, especially since the site still SAYS you're logged in, but just denies you any access.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps CCTray gets around this?

what's the authentication mechanism you are using (forms, windows auth, federated, etc.)?

Our CC.Net servers I make changes to about every 5 minutes while I'm working on setting up a project and have never seen this error. Everyone does run CCTray, but the cc.net servers are not internet accessible so no login is required. The IIS manages authentication seamlessly through ActiveDirectory. Is your cc.net server internet facing?